# universal login name

Tags: php, login-script

Is there a way to make the username part work for both upper and lower case, for example if my username were robert if you entered Robert it would work as well? Attached is a copy of my login script.

```
<?php

session_start();

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if ($username&&$password)
{

$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","*i*****5_******","*******") or die ("Couldn't Connect"); //host,username,password
mysql_select_db("virtua15_gateway") or die ("Could not find database");

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username='$username'");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($numrows!=0)
{
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
            $dbusername = $row['username'];
            $dbpassword = $row['password'];
    }
    if ($username==$dbusername&&md5($password)==$dbpassword)
    {
     header( 'Location: index2.php' );
     $_SESSION['username']=$dbusername;
    }
    else
        echo "incorrect username and password";
}
   else
     die ("This user does not exist");

}
else
    die("Please enter a username and a password")


?>
```

Comment: There are so many problems with this script. MD5 is broken, it's horribly susceptible to SQL injection, if two users can have the same username only the last one will be recognised, otherwise you're looping over a resultset that should have only one row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi try strtolower() function.

```
$username = strtolower($_POST['username']);
```

Check this http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php

Answer (score 2):

check strtolower($username) == strtolower($dbusername)

I'm a bit confused why you're checking it twice though.  You've already checked in your sql query if the usernames match.  Also, are your username's not unique? Why are you doing a while loop and not just a if (false !== ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {}

Also, you should make sure your $dbusername and $dbpassword get defined because if a row is not found, they won't be, and PHP will issue a warning about undefined variables when you access them.

Also, you should be checking if the $_POST keys are set. I tend to code a bit paranoid, but I like to make notices/warning very hard to get. If your server were set to display errors, a user could see either a rather ugly error message, or potentially even sensitive data.

Also, while I'm being way overly picky, as per the HTTP specification, the Location header expects a full URL, not just a relative file name (though all browsers support just a relative file name).

Answer (score 2):

Convert to either lower/upper case or make a case insensitive match.

**Important**

Please don't do this:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username='$username'");
```

As it will allow hackers to perform SQL injection! Please sanitise ALL of your inputs!

IE,

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
```

**Important**

Edit :: Also, NEVER use PHP to do the job of php

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username='$username'");
```

Is **wrong**, you should perform the sql query with your login logic!

IE

```
"SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username='$username' AND password='" . md5($password) . '"
```

Then you can just say this instead

```
if(mysql_num_rows($query)){
   // Login logic
}
```

Edit ::
SQL queries are case insensitive

Answer (score 1):

You can check by two tyes:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
            strtoupper($dbusername) = strtoupper($row['username']);
            $dbpassword = $row['password'];
    }
```

OR

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
        {
                strtolower($dbusername) = strtolower($row['username']);
                $dbpassword = $row['password'];
        }
```

Use any one of them.
this will resolve your problem.

Comment: That's not valid PHP. Perhaps you meant an if clause with ==?

Comment: my mean is that use any one of them.

Comment: Right, he can use either strtolower or strtoupper, but the example presented is invalid syntax.

Comment: Why people use the while loop even when one and only one result is expected? I've seen it often around here, I was just wondering about the logic behind this....

Comment: This answer is based on the requirement as in the question he asked.

Answer (score 1):

A working alternative in MySQL:

```
mysql_query(
    "SELECT * FROM Users 
         WHERE LOWER( username) = LOWER( '" . mysql_real_escape_string( $username) . "')"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to allow login irrespective of the case , I mean Robert, robert, ROBERT, RoBeRT etc.. , then you can consider storing the username in lowercase in the database and while retrieving convert the username to lowercase and execute the query

Comment: MySQL is case-insensitive (usually) on WHERE clauses, therefore storing it lower-cased is not necessary.